# LINQ - Group By Date, filtering and selecting

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I'm relatively new to LINQ and could use some assistance.  Given the following structure:

```
Public Class BaseRate
    Public Property EffectiveDate As DateTime
    Public Property PayRate As Decimal
End Class
```

I have an `IEnumerable(Of BaseRate)` that hold several objects.  There could be data in the collection that has duplicate dates, and some may not.  My business requirement is as follows:

1. Filter out all `BaseRate` objects with `EffectiveDate.Date > objDate.Date`  (`objDate` being supplied in the function)
2. Of the remaining objects, order them in descending order and grab the "highest" `EffectiveDate.Date` from the collection.
3. Grab all `BaseRate` objects that match that "highest" `EffectiveDate.Date`
4. Return that collection

I thought I was getting close with the following:

```
Dim distinct_dates As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of DateTime, BaseRate)) _
                 = Me.GroupBy(Function(o) o.EffectiveDate.Date)

Dim active_at_date As IEnumerable(Of BaseRate) = distinct_dates.Select( _
            Function(grp) grp.OrderByDescending( _
            Function(o) o.EffectiveDate.Date).Where( _
            Function(o) o.EffectiveDate.Date <= objDate.Date))
```

However, I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.DateTime,BaseRate],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BaseRate]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BaseRate]'.

I'm sure I have something in the wrong order, but not sure what.

I did this in VB.NET and methods syntax but feel free to reply in any of the other.  I can translate as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing `FirstOrDefault` call.

LINQ looks much more clear in C#, so my answer will be in C#, as you said you could translate it into VB.

```
var results = source.Where(x => x.EffectiveDate.Date > objDate.Date)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.EffectiveDate)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: That was it.   Thanks!   And for anyone who reads this, technically the filter for the date goes the other way (as I worded it kind of awkwardly in my description).   Final VB version:  `Dim active_at_date = Me.Where(Function(baseRate) baseRate.EffectiveDate.Date <= objDate.Date) _
                          .GroupBy(Function(baseRate) baseRate.EffectiveDate.Date) _
                          .OrderByDescending(Function(grp) grp.Key) _
                          .FirstOrDefault()`